# Angular Material Design: How to layout a stacked set of elements horizontically?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material, stacked

I want to arrange a set of , that are generated from a database and thus the set has a **dynamic amount of md-input-containers**. Also, the width of each md-input-containers is variable. The width is also defined in the database (for each md-input-container).

**I would like to create a "stacked" arrangement** of these md-input-containers on some kind of panel. The panel should take 80% width of the screen, and the md-input-containers should arrange horizontally until there is no more space left on the row, and then start over on a new line.

As I do not know the width of the elements at design-time, a row could take one or more md-input-containers.

I started to try the MD layout system, but I realize that this is something static.

I would appreciate if somebody could kick me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Is css-column an opinion?

```
-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
column-count: 3;
```

If you know that one md-input-container needs a specific width, you could calculate and set the amount of columns dynamically.